# Two way Serial Communication not possible with Qt and Arduino

Tags: qt, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to do a sample application using Qt to communicate to Arduino board DUE.

But When one communication is started other is not able to connect,meaning when i start my Arduino first I am not able to start Qt application to read or write data and viceversa.

Can anybody tell me whether this is possible if Yes please help me in this and i ll try to post my sample code.

Comment: Definitely post your code and clarify what it is you are trying to do. If you are trying to do what Sergio's answer suggests (connecting to the same serial port used by the Arduino IDE) then that won't work. If you're just trying to get any serial communication between your PC and Arduino to work, that's pretty basic and doesn't really have much to do with Qt specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to connect to your *Arduino device* (via its USB to RS232 converter) while the *Arduino IDE*, and thus, the serial monitor **is running**.

If that's the case, that is simply not possible. Not because of Qt, nor because of Arduino. That's the way **serial ports work**. You can't connect to the same port twice from different processes.

Since the microcontroller on the *Arduino DUE* has **4 UARTS**, you may consider using one of them (with **another** USB to serial adapter, and thus, having another COM port showing up on your PC) to interface the board with your Qt application while the Arduino IDE is still connected to the "main" serial port.

Also, keep in mind that the *Arduino Du*e works with **3.3 V**, so ensure that the USB to serial adapter is compatbile with that voltage range.